# creating a custom layout/button

Tags: c#, winforms

Im developing a c# windows form program and i have a form which takes certain information and translates it into buttons in a layout box.

Is it possible to make custom buttons/ forms to be listed in a flow layout box?
I want to make a button which looks like its split into 3 and each section have a different piece of information.

the photo shows the layout of the button im trying to make, this button would be repeated several times but with different information

[image]

Comment: windows form, it wont let me crop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starter UserControl using a TableLayoutPanel:

1. Click on Project --> Add User Control --> Type in a Name (I used
   "TriButton") --> Add Button.
2. Add a TableLayout Panel and set its
   Dock Property to Fill.
3. Click the "..." in the Columns Property. Set Column1 to 25%, and leave Column2 at 50%.  *This will make Column 1 take up 1/3 of the Width, and Column2 take up 2/3 of the Width because 50 is twice as big as 25.
4. Add a Button (button1) in the Top Left Cell of the TableLayout
   Panel.  Set its Dock Property to Fill, and its RowSpan Property to 2.
5. Add a Button (button2) in the Top Right Cell of the TableLayoutPanel.  Set its Dock Property to Fill.
6. Add a Button (button3) in the Bottom Right Cell of the TableLayoutPanel.  Set its Dock Property to Fill.

Try resizing the UserControl to see how it behaves:
[image: TriButton UserControl]

Compile or run the app and the new UserControl should appear at the Top of your ToolBox.

You'll need to add appropriate Properties if you want to be able to get/set the Button values from outside the UserControl, and it might be a good idea to give the UserControl custom Button Click events.

**Alternate approach**

Here's an example of creating the layout as a background image for the button:

[image: TriButton layout via a background image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size sz = new Size(300, 150);
        TriButton btn = new TriButton(sz, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

}

public class TriButton : Button
{

    private String ID;
    private String Information;
    private DateTime Date;

    public TriButton(Size initialSize, String ID, String Information, DateTime Date)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Information = Information;
        this.Date = Date;
        this.Size = initialSize;
        this.SizeChanged += TriButton_SizeChanged;
        this.CreateBackgroundImage();
        this.Text = "";
        this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
        this.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.Overlay;
    }

    private void TriButton_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CreateBackgroundImage();
    }

    private void CreateBackgroundImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
        Rectangle A = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(this.ClientRectangle.Width / 3, this.ClientRectangle.Height));
        Rectangle B = new Rectangle(new Point(A.Right, 0), new Size(this.ClientRectangle.Width - A.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height / 2));
        Rectangle C = new Rectangle(new Point(A.Right, B.Bottom), new Size(B.Width, B.Height));
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(this.BackColor);
            using (Pen p = new Pen(SystemColors.ActiveBorder))
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(p, A);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, B);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, C);
            }
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
            {
                g.DrawString(this.ID, this.Font, b, A, sf);
                g.DrawString(this.Information, this.Font, b, B, sf);
                g.DrawString(this.Date.ToShortDateString(), this.Font, b, C, sf);
            }  
        }
        this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    }

}
```

Comment: would this produce  button or three?

Comment: this is great but how can I put the table layout within the button? I want 1 button instead of 3 but with the text staying where it is

Comment: This will make **three** buttons.  WinForms won't let you make one Button laid out like that (move to **WPF** if you need more flexible layout control like that).  Possible workarounds might be to make a dynamic **Image** that has the text laid out like you want and then set that image as the BackgroundImage() of the Button.  Another option would be to make a series of Labels arranged within the TableLayoutPanel and then manually code the entire UserControl to behave like a Button.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ive been playing with this idea most of the day but ive resorted putting three lines on the button and putting the information in the three lines with spaces to space out the text. I did get the layout that i wanted in custom controls but like you said above it didnt behave like a button Keeps it simple as im still learning.

Comment: See updated code for an example of creating a dynamic image with the text arranged in it.

Comment: That is fantastic. I didnt realize that you could create an image through code. Thanks alot for your help Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class and paste the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsLayoutButton
{
    class FlowLayoutButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
    {
        public FlowLayoutButton()
        {
            Label labelLeft = new Label();
            labelLeft.Text = "12345478";
            labelLeft.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            labelLeft.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            TableLayoutPanel horizontalLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            horizontalLayout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            horizontalLayout.ColumnCount = 2;
            horizontalLayout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            horizontalLayout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            horizontalLayout.Controls.Add(labelLeft, 0, 0);
            horizontalLayout.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

            Label labelTop = new Label();
            labelTop.Text = "Some Information";
            labelTop.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            labelTop.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            Label labelBottom = new Label();
            labelBottom.Text = "Date";
            labelBottom.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            labelBottom.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            TableLayoutPanel verticalLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
            verticalLayout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            verticalLayout.RowCount = 2;
            verticalLayout.RowStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            verticalLayout.RowStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50f));
            verticalLayout.Controls.Add(labelTop, 0, 0);
            verticalLayout.Controls.Add(labelBottom, 0, 1);

            horizontalLayout.Controls.Add(verticalLayout, 1, 0);

            this.Controls.Add(horizontalLayout);

            Control[] controls = new Control[] { horizontalLayout, verticalLayout, labelLeft, labelTop, labelBottom };
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.Click += (sender, e) => { this.OnClick(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseDown += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseDown(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseUp += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseUp(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseEnter(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseLeave(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.Enter += (sender, e) => { this.OnEnter(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.Leave += (sender, e) => { this.OnLeave(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.GotFocus += (sender, e) => { this.OnGotFocus(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.LostFocus += (sender, e) => { this.OnLostFocus(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.KeyPress += (sender, e) => { this.OnKeyPress(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.KeyDown += (sender, e) => { this.OnKeyDown(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.KeyUp += (sender, e) => { this.OnKeyUp(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseClick += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseClick(e); }; });
            forEachControl(controls, (control) => { control.MouseDoubleClick += (sender, e) => { this.OnMouseDoubleClick(e); }; });
        }

        private void forEachControl(Control[] controls, Action<Control> action)
        {
            foreach(Control control in controls) { action(control); }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can create your button dynamically:

```
namespace WindowsFormsLayoutButton
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FlowLayoutButton button = new FlowLayoutButton();
            button.Left = 16;
            button.Top = 8;
            button.Width = 256;
            button.Height = 96;
            this.Controls.Add(button);

            button.Click += (o, args) => { MessageBox.Show("clicked"); };
        }
    }
}
```